# Compiling object c (.m) file to an object file(.o) in osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, gcc

Thanks for reviewing the problem. There is an object c file called try.m, and I complie it to an object file try.o with the command:

```
gcc -c try.m -o try.o -framework Foundation
```

the try.h is

```
int print_word( void );
```

The try.m is:

```
#include "try.h" 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int print_word( void )
{
  NSLog (@"say hello");
  return 0;
}
```

Additionly, there is a main.c file, which contain the main() function, and it looks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "try.h"

int main()
{
   printf( "This is main\n");
}
```

I compile main.c to main.o by the following command:

```
gcc -o main.o -c main.c
```

Then, I link the main.o and try.o to form the executable file main:

```
gcc  -o main main.o try.o
```

After these steps, the following errors happened:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLlmb.jpg)

The errors are:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_NSLog", referenced from:
    _print_word in try.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64    
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How could these errors be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link against the Foundation framework. You can do it all in a single command: `gcc main.c try.m -framework Foundation`.

Comment: Thanks @EricS. Is there method to compile main.o and try.o seperately, and then combine them to form an executable file, as presented in my question?

Comment: gcc -o try.o -c try.m; gcc -o main.o -c main.c; gcc main.o try.o -framework Foundation